# Increase size of filesystem /dev/sdb1 after increasing the size of /dev/sdb

Tags: linux, filesystems

For the FS

```
$ df -kh /store 

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sdb1        50G   45G  1.9G  97% /store
```

I have increased the size of `/dev/sdb` by **20G** and then added the space to `/dev/sdb1` by **20G** by deleting the partition and creating it again

```
sdb               8:16   0   70G  0 disk 
└─sdb1            8:17   0   70G  0 part
```

However I am not sure how to make it visible in `/store`

`pvresize` gives the error as: **no physical volume found**

It is a cloud VM vgs or vgdisplay does not show any VG created as well

Output of fstab as below:

```
/dev/sdb1 /store/ ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`pvresize` is not applicable to your situation because you are clearly not using LVM: your filesystem is located on a normal disk partition, not on a LVM logical volume. That's also the reason why `vgs` or `vgdisplay` show nothing.

Since your filesystem type is `ext4`, the only remaining step to make the added space usable is:

```
resize2fs /dev/sdb1   # specific to ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems
```

or

```
fsadm resize /dev/sdb1  # works at least with ext2/3/4, XFS and ReiserFS
```

Either command can be used while the filesystem is mounted and in use.

Older systems might have `resize2fs` but not `fsadm`.